# Some performance counters shows wrong values after installing .net 4.5

Tags: asp.net, performancecounter

after installing .NET 4.5 on a Windows Web Server 2008 R2, some performance counters shows the wrong values. I'm using the built in Performance Monitor and looking at the group
ASP.NET Apps v4.0.30319 for counters Anonymous Requests/Sec and Requests Executing.

Before those values reflected the current load with fluctuating values, but now they instead increases for each request, so they behave more like Total Requests and Total Requests Executing.

We have seen the same behavior in a production environment and also on internal servers.

Have any of you seen the same behavior, I can find anything when googling for it.

Regards
Patrik

Comment: Thanks for reporting this issue. I could repro the issue locally. Dev will be looking into this soon. I will keep you posted on this thread.  In the mean time it will be great if you can file a connect bug and let me know the id of the connect bug. this will give you proper credit of reporting the bug when it will be fixed.

Comment: Also it looks like this issue repros only on Windows web server 2k8 R2 edition. Doesn't happen on Win2k8 R2 standard edition.

Comment: Hi Anand, thank you for helping out. I've posted on connect with ID: 765656. I will try using the standard edition to see if that works for us as well.

Comment: Hi @Anand, we just tried a Win2k8 R2 Standard edition, but unfortunately we see the same behavior there.

Comment: thank you Patrik for details.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Fix for this issue is available now. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2805227 for windows8 and http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2805226 for windows 7 platform.
So below workaround is no longer required.

The workaround for this issue is to execute below commands from 4.5 installed directory, (e.g. “%systemroot%\Microsoft.Net\Framework64\v4.0.30319”)

1. aspnet_regiis -u
2. aspnet_regiis -I or aspnet_regiis -iru

Comment: This works on our test servers, will try in production later this week. Thanks!

Comment: warning, this will change the .net version for all the application pools currently using .net 4 or 4.5 and set .net 2 !

Comment: The MS hotfix, is this Win Server 2012 only?

Comment: Thanks Luke and Rolando for your comments. I have updated links in my answer with framework updates on Windows8 and Windows7 platforms. As FYI... There is one more update available related .Net 4.5 and it is not related to this issue.(http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2805222 for windows 8 and http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2805221 for windows 7 platform)

Comment: It worked for me installing both updates: 2805221 and 2805226 , it requires reboot !

Answer (score 1):

One thing that comes to mind is permissions on this registry key:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\version of ASP.NET\Names
```

I'd start off by checking those and ensuring they're correct.  If you have multiple versions you can even cross-check/compare the settings (ie if 2.0 still works fine)..